# How to assign a string-value to a variable with exec()?

Tags: python, string, exec

I know there are plenty of these questions already, but I still couldn't figure out a solution for my problem:

I am trying to assign an unknown string value (like "M10" or something similar) to an unknown variable name by using `exec`. Therefore I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
name  = "test"
value = "m10"
exec("%s=%s" % (name, value), globals())
exec("{}={}".format(name, value), globals())
print(test)
```

It throws this error: `NameError: name 'm10' is not defined`.

As soon as I change the value to `10` for example, it works totally fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This is almost 100% a XY problem. What is that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be doing this, but the problem is that `m10` **is not a string**, it is simply a reference to some variable, which isnt defined. `"m10"` is a string literal. Again, you probably should jsut not be using exec to begin with

Comment: Just to emphasize on the two comments above: **you should certainly not do this**.

Comment: You don't need `exec()`. You can use `globals()[name] = value` to assign the value of the `value` variable (the string `"m10"`) to the `test` variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

quotes around m10, it thinks you're trying to assign a variable to test

```
value = "'m10'"
```

Comment: OOOOOH! Thanks, that totally makes sense!